# Copying contents from an NTFS disk to exFAT formatted disk

Tags: linux, windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs, exfat

Will there be any problem if I copy contents from an NTFS hard disk to an exFAT hard disk? I will take files from Windows 7 on an NTFS external HDD and copy them on a Fedora machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/240928/convert-ntfs-volume-to-exfat-without-losing-contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues. You may need to install a NTFS driver in Fedora. To do this run the following commands:
To become root:

```
 su -
```

To install ntfs-3g:

```
yum install ntfs-3g
```

After ntfs-3g is installed you should be able to read/write to the NTFS external hard drive. More info on ntfs-3g can be found [here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/ntfs-3g)

Answer (score 3):

There will be no problem except that you'll lose all the **file permissions** (and **encrypted files**, if any)

Another possible problem if you have *tons of small files*: your files [will consume more space on disk](https://serverfault.com/q/893206/343888) because [ExFAT uses 64KB cluster by default](https://superuser.com/q/1151976/241386)

[Please explain wasted space on an exFAT formatted external hard drive](https://superuser.com/q/365739/241386)