# Why is the default allocation unit size smaller (2048 bytes) for exFAT than for NTFS (4096 bytes) when formatting a disk on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs, exfat, allocation-unit

I see that the default allocation unit size is smaller for exFAT (2048 bytes) than for NTFS (4096 bytes) when formatting a disk on Windows 7 via Windows Explorer:

[image]
[image]

Why is the default allocation unit size smaller (2048 bytes) for exFAT than for NTFS (4096 bytes)?

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation for the `exFAT` it should be **128KB** for volume size _32 GB–256 TB_ capacity, on the Windows 7: [Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95)

Comment: *"Why is the default allocation unit size smaller (2048 bytes) for exFAT than for NTFS (4096 bytes)?"* -- You're not reading the screen correctly.  I see an allocation size of 2MB (actually "2048 **kilo**bytes") in the exFAT window on the right side.  So 2MB for exFAT is not smaller than 4KB for NTFS.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt:  Check answers for this post: [Why is exFAT's default allocation size in Windows so high?](https://superuser.com/q/1151976/1266966).